# Unique on an array of hashes based on value

Tags: ruby

I feel like this could be improved (a common feeling in ruby).  I'm trying to uniq an array of hashes based on value.  In this example, I want the colors of the elements.  Moss and snow are impostors.

```
# remove unique array of hashes based on a hash value

a = [
  { :color => "blue", :name => "water" },
  { :color => "red", :name => "fire" },
  { :color => "white", :name => "wind" },
  { :color => "green", :name => "earth" },
  { :color => "green", :name => "moss" },
  { :color => "white", :name => "snow" }
]

# remove moss and snow
uniques = []
a.each_with_index do |r, i|
  colors = uniques.collect {|e| e[:color]}

  if !colors.include? r[:color]
    uniques.push r
  else
    a[i] = nil
  end
end

a.compact!

puts a
```

This will print

```
{:color=>"blue", :name=>"water"}
{:color=>"red", :name=>"fire"}
{:color=>"white", :name=>"wind"}
{:color=>"green", :name=>"earth"}
```

Which is "correct" however I feel like this is excessive.  My experience with .map .inject is limited and those advanced techniques elude me.  If someone could re-factor this, it might help me understand another terse technique.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9, try the following

```
a.uniq! {|e| e[:color] }
```

Comment: It's not solving the OPs question. While it filters unique colors, it doesn't reject the non-elements if the array order is different.

Comment: I answered the OPs original question "to uniq an array of hashes based on value" or as the quote states "remove unique array of hashes based on a hash value." What is ambiguous is the example: it removes "moss and snow," but does not say why they were removed.  I assumed they were removed because they were duplicate colors: that is why the original code removed them. @the Tin Man assumes they were removed because they are not elements due to the example's explanation.

Comment: "assumes they were removed because they are not elements due to the example's explanation ", No, the OP said, "In this example, I want the colors of the elements. Moss and snow are impostors.", and in the example shows that they have been removed. The elements are "fire", "air", "earth" and "water". This solution fails if the array changes; An example is at the end of my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified that the order in my example data is significant.  In my specific case, I sort them and don't mind if I lose the second value.  Thanks for the more general solution Tin Man, it's certainly more reliable.

Comment: Just a note to mention that there's a nondestructive version as well: `#uniq { ... }`.

Answer (score 6):

I'd go with Array's `reject` or `select` methods:

```
require 'pp'

a = [
  { :color => "blue", :name => "water" },
  { :color => "red", :name => "fire" },
  { :color => "white", :name => "wind" },
  { :color => "green", :name => "earth" },
  { :color => "green", :name => "moss" },
  { :color => "white", :name => "snow" }
]

pp a.reject{ |h| %w[moss snow].include?( h[:name]) } 
# >> [{:color=>"blue", :name=>"water"},
# >>  {:color=>"red", :name=>"fire"},
# >>  {:color=>"white", :name=>"wind"},
# >>  {:color=>"green", :name=>"earth"}]
```

Alternately you can be positive about it and `select` the ones you want to keep:

```
pp a.select{ |h| %w[water fire wind earth].include?( h[:name] ) } 
# >> [{:color=>"blue", :name=>"water"},
# >>  {:color=>"red", :name=>"fire"},
# >>  {:color=>"white", :name=>"wind"},
# >>  {:color=>"green", :name=>"earth"}]
```

You're not really dealing with hashes, it's an array that happens to contain hashes, so don't let them confuse you. Array methods like `reject` and `select` are core methods for filtering out unwanted, or keeping wanted, elements.

In your code sample, you're losing sight of what your objective is: You want the elements, rejecting "moss" and "snow", which are non-elements. Filter out the non-elements, and you're left with the correct/real elements in the hashes. From there you can extract the correct colors.

An additional problem to watch out for with using `uniq`, is it is positional, in other words, it looks for the first unique value and rejects subsequent ones. This wasn't apparent in your code because your array was consistently the same order as you tested. If you shuffled the order though...:

```
2.times do
  pp a.shuffle.uniq{ |h| h[:color] }
end
```

Pass #1...

```
# [{:color=>"red", :name=>"fire"},
#  {:color=>"white", :name=>"wind"},
#  {:color=>"green", :name=>"moss"},
#  {:color=>"blue", :name=>"water"}]
```

Pass #2...

```
# [{:color=>"green", :name=>"earth"},
#  {:color=>"blue", :name=>"water"},
#  {:color=>"red", :name=>"fire"},
#  {:color=>"white", :name=>"snow"}]
```

Suddenly we see that both "moss" and "snow" are sneaking into the results even though the colors are unique. Those are subtle gotcha's that you have to watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might want an even shorter variant of the [correct answer by Steve Wilhelm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4841279/2553863) ,

**BEWARE**:

```
a.uniq!(&:color)
```

**WILL NOT WORK** for an array of hashes, just like

```
a[1].color
```

wouldn't work either.

For more information on the & operator, read [this link](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/3/7/symbol-to-proc-shorthand), or the comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9926724/2553863) which in turn have plenty of links to resources.

On the other hand, you could get the Symbol#to_proc method working using lambdas, as is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179636/ruby-using-the-methodname-shortcut-from-array-mapmethodname-for-hash-key), though it could be just complicating things, and certainly would not be a shorter version of the correct answer. However, it is very interesting knowledge.

Thanks mukesh-kumar-gupta for the [heads-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841187/unique-on-an-array-of-hashes-based-on-value/50012696?noredirect=1#comment88356967_50012696)

Comment: This will not work in case of array of hashes.  use the @Steve Wilhelm approach.

Comment: You're right. I'll see how to edit it so others don't fall in the same error than I did.

Comment: Edit your original answer and replace old one with and correct one.