# Is there a way to use Ruby map(&:method) shorthand for passing a key to all the hashes in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very used to using the ruby `&` shorthand for array methods, ex:

```
a = [1, 3, 4]
a.map(&:to_f)
# => [1.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

instead of
`a.map {|x| x.to_f }`

Is there an equivalent for an array of hashes? For ex:

```
a = [{'first' => 1, 'second' => 4}, {'first' => 5, 'second' => 6}]
a.map(&:'first')
# => [1, 5]
```

Something like this? That is a shorthand over `a.map { |x| x['first'] }` ?

This would be especially useful when I have large arrays of many nested hashes to drill down into.

Comment: `:'first' == :first` -- it's absolute the same :)

Comment: This is pretty similar to [**using the "&:methodname" shortcut from array.map(&:methodname) for hash key strings rather than methodname**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20179636/479863), isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

[Numbered parameters](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Proc.html#class-Proc-label-Numbered+parameters) were introduced in ruby 2.7 which makes the following a nice short hand way to accomplish what you want.

```rb
a = [{ "first" => 1, "second" => 4 }, { "first" => 5, "second" => 6 }]
a.map {_1['first']}
```